# How to translate label and routerlink in Angular2 with i18n inside constructor

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am new in Angular2 and it is my first time working with internazionalitation so I am stuck and I need your help, please.

I ´ve already translated text inside HTML and now I am working with internazionalitation of .ts files.

My question is: ¿How can I translate label and routelink inside a constructor of a .ts file?

I would like to get this translated:

```
 constructor(private doctypesService: DoctypesService, private categoriasService: CategoriesService, 
          private metadataService: MetadataService, private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService, private i18n: I18n) {
this.breadcrumbService.setItems([
    { label: 'Administración' },
    { label: 'Categorías', routerLink: ['/categorias'] }
]);
```

The two labels and the routerlink.

I ´ve translated values of a table header inside the ts file with this approach and it works, but I don t know how to do it with the labels and routerlink. Thanks for your help

This is what I did in on init to translate headers:

```
ngOnInit() {

this.refreshCategorias();

this.refreshSubcategorias();

this.refreshMetadatos();

this.cols = [
    { field: 'code', header: this.i18n('código')},
    { field: 'name', header: this.i18n('nombre') },
    { field: 'description', header: this.i18n('descripción')}
];
```

}

Of course, I had to make this import to make it work

```
import { I18n } from '@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill';
```

Comment: what do you mean by _translate routerLink_?

Comment: I mean that the value inside routerlink (in this case '/categorias'), should be translated to other language. It is in Spanish and I need it in English for example

Comment: For translations inside of components, your should use the `TranslateService`. See https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

Comment: Your second requirement is a non-trivial issue, see https://github.com/Greentube/localize-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate it by creating an instance of `TranslateService` and calling the `instant()`

Example:

```
     constructor(private doctypesService: DoctypesService, private categoriasService: CategoriesService, 
          private metadataService: MetadataService, private breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService, public translate: TranslateService) {
this.breadcrumbService.setItems([
    { label: this.translate.instant('Administración') },
    { label: this.translate.instant('Categorías'), routerLink: ['/categorias'] }
]);
```